# Set paper size to A5

Tags: paper-size

I want to use this template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/climate-policy-initiative-report-template/kjfjzrcjgtqg#.W4VSO-hKhPY

However, I would like to set the paper size to A5. I've tried a few things, but the cover loses all formatting and I can not fix it.

Do you have any tips?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question. In it's current form the question becomes useless if the link to the external site breaks.

Answer (score 4):

Add `a5paper` to documentclass options, and replace `letterpaper` with `a5paper`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb, amstext, amsmath, epstopdf, booktabs, verbatim, gensymb, geometry, appendix, natbib, lmodern}
\geometry{a5paper}
```

Comment: I did it. However, the cover was wrongly formatted. Can you download the template and try to adjust it, please?